# jQuery load unknown number of json files with error handling

Tags: jquery, json, deferred

I have a an `index.json` file that returns a list of additional `N` JSON files that need to be loaded. They need to be loaded using a differed approach so that when they are all loaded, I can handle them all at once.

Each one of the additional JSON files may or may not exist on the server.

I am using the following approach to load the data, which works fine when all files actually exist on the server:

```
$.getJSON('index.json').then(function (response) {
    var files = response.files;
    $.when
     .apply(null, getDeferreds(files))
     .done(function() {
          //process the files
     })
    });
});

function getDeferreds(files) {
    var deferreds = [], i;
    for (i in files) {
       //file type 1
       deferreds.push(
          $.getJSON(files[i] + '_1.json')
            .then(function (response) {
              //do something
             })
       );
      //file type 2
      deferreds.push(
          $.getJSON(files[i] + '_2.json')
            .then(function (response) {
              //do something
             })
       );
    }
    return deferreds;
};
```

This approach works great, HOWEVER....
When any of the files are missing, i.e `somefile_2.json` (sometimes the index will be created before the file actually exists on the server), the whole process fails and none of the data is being retrieved.

Within `$.getJson (`or `$.get`) I can detect the error using the `.fail()` method, however that doesn't prevent the call from failing and `.done()` is never being called.

How would I refactor this to have the `.done()` method always work even when some files are missing?

Comment: try passing a [second function](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneCallbacks-failCallbacks) to `.then` that returns a placeholder (empty object) for failed requests, like `.then(function () ... , function() { return { }; });`

Comment: That has the same effect as `.fail()`. It detects the 404 error but still causes the whole process to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution was more simple than I thought.

My guess was that somehow along the process when the call fails, the deferred object is not being resolved correctly.

Simply adding `return $.Deferred().resolve();` to the fail callback did the trick.

Posting a full solution with error handling in case it helps someone:

```
$.getJSON('index.json').then(function (response) {
    var files = response.files;
    $.when
     .apply(null, getDeferreds(files))
     .done(function() {
          //process the files
     })
    });
});

function getDeferreds(files) {
    var deferreds = [], i;
    for (i in files) {
         deferreds.push(
           $.getJSON(files[i])
                .then(function (response) {
                   //do something
                }, function() {
                    return $.Deferred().resolve([]);
                })
         );
    };
    return deferreds;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written looks good, providing `do something` includes a return statement to deliver data further down the promise chain (in the caller).

You might consider some tidying, and "cutting the cake"  differently, by :

- aggregating promises in the subfunction
- performing all processing of the delivered data in the caller

It's a matter of preference, but I would probably choose to write :

```
$.getJSON('index.json').then(function (response) {
    return getFileData(response.files);
}).then(function(dataArray) {
        // `dataArray` is an array of data items
        // Do all processing here
    });
});

function getFileData(files) {
    var promises = files.map(function(file) {
        return $.getJSON(file)
        .then(null, // No processing here
        function() {
            return $.when([]); // $.when(value) is a useful shorthand for $.Deferred().resolve(value)
        });
    });
    // By aggregating the promises here, caller(s) can be delivered an array of data items, wrapped in a single promise.
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //convert function's `arguments` to a proper array
    });
};
```

Of course, if `getFileData()` isn't going to be called from elsewhere, you could do everything in the caller.